# Website uses wrong certificate. Is the connection still encrypted?

Tags: http, ssl, encryption, https

I am connecting to a REST-Api. The baseurl is an IP-Adress. The problem is that when I connect with firefox it says:

"Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead:
Firefox does not trust this site because it uses a certificate that is not valid for *ip-adress*. The certificate is only valid for the following names: *domain.at, domain.at"

I know that the server could be compromised, but is the traffic still encrypted?

Comment: "but is the traffic still encrypted?" yes but since you might not be sending it to the endpoint you think sending it to (imagine: on path interception by attacker), it is kind of worthless/besides the point that it is encrypted.

Comment: Encryption is generally used to achieve confidentiality. If man-in-the-middle is a valid attack vector - it usually is - then the messages may not be confidential anymore. If it is just eavesdropping where the real attack happens latter, then yes, the messages may still be secure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about [security](https://security.stackexchange.com) rather than programming.